# Stripe Updating a customer's card info

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe in php and I try to avoid using html forms , I instead call the Stripe Hosted Checkout page for the first subscription payment. However, if for later invoices, the payment failed due to an expired card for example , I want my customer to be able to update his card info (or I can create a new customer object in Stripe belonging to this same person) but the important part is that I want him to enter his NEW credit card info in a stripe hosted form that will validate his new card number , CVV...
Is there any way to do that?

---

Currently I am doing this :

```
document.getElementById("subscribe-now").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    createCheckoutSession('<?php echo Config::SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN_ID; ?>').then(function(data) {
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
          sessionId: data.id
      }).then(handleResult);
    });
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and what research you have done to accomplish this on your own and how you are currently implementing your card system.

Comment: If card is expired, you initiate new subscription checkout and revalidate it, update your subscription object records and be done with it. It's always like re doing things. You hook into checkout callbacks and see if your error requires submitting new data and then initiate form as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's supported by the [Customer Portal](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/customer-portal). Similar to Checkout, this is a Stripe-hosted service that allows your customers to manage subscriptions and saved payment methods according to the [configuration you provide](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/integrating-customer-portal#configure), and you [redirect your customers](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/integrating-customer-portal#redirect) to it.

[Preview here](https://billing.stripe.com/customer-portal-demo).

Comment: Thank you so  much for this great answer Nolan !

Comment: I found this link https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/subscriptions/update-payment-details it states that it "uses Checkout to update subscription payment methods. You can instead implement the Billing customer portal to provide a Stripe-hosted dashboard for your customers to manage their subscriptions and billing details." What is the most desirable way to let  a customer edit his card number before it expires ? Customer portal or checkout session ?

Comment: Customer Portal is more suited to what you're trying to do. You can use either one, but the Checkout version would be a little bit more work for this use case. You'd use Checkout with `mode=setup` to collect a new payment method, then you would need to manage setting that payment method for use with the subscription. The Customer Portal will do that part for you and just have the customer provide the new details & automatically set it to be used with the subscription.